# "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" Mapping Telerik ORM Tables

Tags: c#, oracle, orm, telerik

I am attempting to map an Class to an Oracle table using the Telerik Open Access ORM.

I have mapped several other classes but I'm running into a problem with one table in particular.

This one for example ... works no problem.

```
   public class WIConnectionMapper
    {
        public MappingConfiguration<WIConnection> Map()
        {
            MappingConfiguration<WIConnection> map = new MappingConfiguration<WIConnection>();

            #region map fields to model
            map.MapType(model => new
            {
                MESSAGE_ID      = model.ID,
                PAGER_VERSION   = model.Version,
                TIME_STAMP      = model.TimeStamp,
                HOSTNAME        = model.Hostname,
                STATUS          = model.Status,
                LAN_IP          = model.LanIP,
                WAN_IP          = model.WanIP,
                GATEWAY         = model.Gateway

            }).ToTable("XFE_REP.WI_CONNECTION");
            #endregion map fields to model

            #region define columns

            map.HasProperty(e => e.ID)
                .HasColumnType("number")
                .HasPrecision(10)
                .HasScale(0)
                .IsNullable()
                .IsIdentity();

            map.HasProperty(e => e.Version)
                .HasColumnType("number")
                .HasPrecision(10)
                .HasScale(0)
                .IsNullable();

            // MAP REMAINING COLUMNS

            #endregion define columns

            return map;
        }
    }
```

This one below (PinToPagerIDMapper), however throws an "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" exception when the context is initialized.

```
public class PinToPagerIDMapper
{
    public MappingConfiguration<PinToPagerID> Map()
    {
        MappingConfiguration<PinToPagerID> map = new MappingConfiguration<PinToPagerID>();

        #region map fields to model
        map.MapType(model => new
        {

            ASSET_NUMBER         = model.AssetNumber,
            WIRELESS_PAGER_PIN   = model.PIN,
            EFFECTIVE_START_DATE = model.EffectiveStartDate,
            EFFECTIVE_END_DATE   = model.EffectiveEndDate

        }).ToTable("XFE_REP.PIN2PAGERID");
        #endregion map fields to model

        #region define columns

        map.HasProperty(e => e.AssetNumber)
            .HasColumnType("varchar2")
            .WithVariableLength(15)
            .IsNotNullable();

        map.HasProperty(e => e.PIN)
            .HasColumnType("varchar2")
            .WithVariableLength(50)
            .IsNotNullable();

        map.HasProperty(e => e.EffectiveStartDate)
            .HasColumnType("date")
            .IsNullable();

        map.HasProperty(e => e.EffectiveEndDate)
            .HasColumnType("date")
            .IsNullable();

        #endregion define columns

        return map;
    }
}
```

I have verified that table name, case, schema/user and permissions are all correct. The only thing that I see that could be a problem (?) is that there is a NUMBER in the table name. Is that a "no no" for the ORM? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Not sure where else to look or what to do.

Comment: I was just reading something on the Telerik site ... is it possible that this could be caused because the table lacks an identity column?

Comment: That was it. When I added IsIdentity() to the appropriate column(s) in the mapping it started working.